# Redefinition of default argument

Tags: c++, default-arguments

I have encounter an error saying "redefinition of default argument" while I am compiling some codes. This is the line that is throwing the error:

```
bool wCommandDistributor::initialise (const bool server = true, const short ncmds=0,
                byte (*cmds)[CMD_MAX_RECLEN] = (byte (*)[CMD_MAX_RECLEN])0)
```

Is there anyway that I can rewrite the code in order to solve the error? This is not a code written by me. I am helping to rewrite the code and it is written in C++.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14):

The compiler says it all, you are redefining the default arguments of `initialise` (even though they might be the same).

The default arguments were probably already defined in the function declaration. You don't need to redefine them in the function definition, and so you should remove them.

But only the ones that were already defined in the declaration, it might be that some were *not* defined in the declaration, only in the definition. In this case you should naturally leave them.

Comment: I understanding about removing the declaration: `const bool server = true, const short ncmds=0` and define them at another place. However, my problem lies in: `byte (*cmds)[CMD_MAX_RECLEN] = (byte (*)[CMD_MAX_RECLEN])0`.

Comment: @user1744424 I don't understand the problem, just remove the default argument declarations `= true`, `= 0` and `(byte(*)[CMD_MAX_RECLEN])0`

Comment: yes but after I remove the declarations, how do I redeclare for `byte (*cmds)[CMD_MAX_RECLEN] = (byte (*)[CMD_MAX_RECLEN])0` as just declaring that statement gives me an error.

Comment: @user1744424 why do you want to redeclare it?

Comment: @user1744424 I'm really confused, sorry. You don't need to specify the default arguments for the definition, because you already specified them in the declaration - `initialise(const bool server, const short ncmds, byte(*cmds)[CMD_MAX_RECLEN]` Can you explain the specific problem that you are having please?

Comment: Yes. If I did not remove the declaration from the function, it throws a redefine error. But if I remove the declaration and define elsewhere, it throw an "internal error: assertion failed:lower_expr: bad kind". By declaration I mean this declaration: "byte (*cmds)[CMD_MAX_RECLEN] = (byte (*)[CMD_MAX_RECLEN])0". The body of the function uses the array so I can't just remove the declaration.

Comment: @user1744424 Where elsewhere? And what happens if you just remove `=(byte(*)[CMD_MAX_RECLEN])0` from the code you posted??